# WordPress - Permalink custom Structure - 404

Tags: permalinks

I am trying to setup permalinks in wordPress so that URLs looks like this...

```
Main Blog Page
www.example.com/blog

Single Blog Posts
www.example.com/blog/category_name/post_title

Category Page
www.example.com/blog/category_name
```

I have set Custom Structure to...

```
/blog/%category%/%postname%
```

All pages are working correctly apart from blog posts, they are giving me a 404 error, anyone any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: First, if you use caching plugin, clear the cache. Also you'd better click 'save settings' button again under permalink setting page.

Comment: no need to click save when you go to the permalinks section if you're just refreshing the permamlinks.  Just visiting that page will do the trick